# Rendering packaging files with other textures

Tags: rendering, scripting

I have created a packaging model and I have to render several packaging lay-outs on the same model.

For example a 4 boxes of thee.
1 model
4 graphic designs in a directory
How can I create a batch or script that will render the 4 designs?

[image]

Comment: Hi I assume you want 4 textures to be switched on a single object.
I don't know how to make a script but you can make a driver setup on a single texture having 4 of these inside and switching them based on the frame count.
or make these texture a sequence and render it.
let's see what kind of idea does others have :D

Comment: If you need all the boxes to be in the same render, I would recommend linking the material to the object data instead of the mesh data, but you may want each box to be in its own render, in which case I’m not sure what you should do. The other user’s suggestion sounded workable, but if you had more than 4 textures at any time it wouldn’t be so great. Exactly what do you need?

Comment: Hi, each box should have it's own render and we are talking about more than 4 textures.

Comment: I'm working in a graphic design department. We are creating new designs for packaging. And we are talking about rendering dozens of packs.
The goal is to link a model via a script to a folder with all the textures to be rendered. Basically a batch to render in bulk.